# Is an user space on a MCU possible?

Tags: microcontroller

I'm currently researching the possibility of making some kind of user space on an MCU. User space is probably not the right therm here.
What we want is space on the memory that a user can freely use to add code and execute it. The rest of the memory will be used for the bootloader and some kind of library/package that the user space can "use".

Normally you would just compile the whole code, so including the 
(precompiled) library and user code and then flash it to the MCU. But we are afraid that the library can be reverse engineered. So we want some way to "fix" the library on the MCU to at least make it harder to reverse engineer.

When I try to research this subject I only get results about Operating Systems, so probally user space is the wrong therm. I'm struggling to find more information about this. Is this possible, does it even make sence to do something like this?

The MCU in question has a Core-M4

Comment: Will it be enough reverse engineering protection to provide your library precompiled? So the user will only compile his own sources.

Comment: never say never but generally an MCU is wide open, it is not a hardened processor with protection layers like you would run an operating system on.  There may be exceptions but assume that you cant do this.  Some of the hard to call MCUs because of their size, etc (cortex-m7 maybe m4) might have such features, maybe the cortex-m32 and 22 have such features.

Comment: nothing prohibits you from having several/dozens of separately compiled items that make up the whole of the MCU firmware, some of which can be user code.  In general dont expect the user code to be unable to see the libraries, search through specific chip/families to see if there are exceptions to this.   operating system results are useful it is an operating system kind of thing not that you do or dont want an OS but if they have os like features like some sort of mmu and some sort of priority/protection scheme you can use that.

Comment: Is user code possible in any language or sand-boxed (like for example running under an interpreter, such as Lua)?

Comment: @old_timer I'm using a core-m4. how would such a feature be called?

Comment: @DavidMichaelHuber We are not sure about this, that's why we are researching other ways

Comment: Just found [this](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0439b/BIHJJABA.html). The Cortex M4 seems to have a so called "Memory Protection Unit". It says it can be used to enforce privilege rules, separate processes and enforce access rules. Enforce access rules sounds interesting regarding your question I think.

Comment: the mpu is optional at build time, not all cortex-m4s will show up in chips with this feature.

Comment: trying to figure out how much is really protected.  to answer your question your answers are in the arm documentation primarily the armv7-m architectural reference manual.  privileged and unprivileged thread mode.